# Downvoting a post when you do not understand, but does not violate any reasons

Tags: discussion

With reference to my recent question,
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38007164/grep-is-not-grepping-consistent-with-values

From the comments, it is quite obvious that even highly rep-ed people here don't understand the question.

My command is a correct command and it works, but when a small modification is added, it stopped working correctly.

Due to the understanding of the '-v' is not understand, it is quite obvious that I got down-voted due to that.

Should this be the case?

Comment: @honk:  No, it really isn't.

Comment: @Makoto: Well, I still think so. There are some requests for clarification in the comments. Maybe those users had the impression that the question is unclear or underspecified. This is covered in the linked duplicate.

Comment: People are *supposed* to downvote questions that are unclear.  So if the readers of your question can't understand it, then the *appropriate* course of action for them to take is to downvote it.  It is then up to you to realize that readers aren't able to understand it and work to improve the clarity of the question so that future readers *will* be able to understand it.

Comment: It's been less than a full day since the meta question was posted, but the original question under discussion is long gone already.  It's incredibly poor form to post a link to your own SO question on a meta site, and then delete that SO question.  The majority of readers of the meta question have absolutely no idea what you're talking about, beyond the vagaries of "something that I didn't like happened", and some hand-waving about details that aren't at all evident in the meta question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It really *isn't* obvious why one gets downvoted, sometimes.  You could assume that it's someone who doesn't understand your question, or you could guess otherwise - I mean, someone could have had their kid click the mouse *just* as it hovered over downvote, or they could've [lost their keys](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/215397/175248) and downvoted your question all the same.

My advice in this scenario would be to pay close attention to the comments and at least attempt to address them.  There is at least one call for you to post more complete code, and that would be in your best interests.  I wouldn't focus on why someone downvoted; instead, I'd focus on making the question as clear and as complete as I can.

If I feel like I've done that, though...I leave it alone.  Not much else I could really do except wait for someone else to come along and see if they understand the question a bit better.